# How to unhide a VM in Xen?

Tags: virtual-machines, xen, xenserver

After failed OVF import, I have some VMs which are appearing in XenCenter only if I enable *Hidden Objects* option in *View* menu.
How can I unhide a hidden Virtual Machine in Xen Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the server console:

a. To find the UUID of the hidden VM, type the following xe command:

```
xe vm-list
```

Make note of the UUID of the hidden VM.

b. To unhide the VM, type the following xe command:

```
xe vm-param-remove uuid=<vm-uuid> param-name=other-config param-key=HideFromXenCenter
```

Enter the UUID of the hidden VM from step a.

*reference:http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX125120*

Comment: Is this not extremely dangerous? The above command clears the whole other-config parameter, which normally bears several other parameters as a map too. Why not just "unhide" the vm by issuing the following command:
xe vm-param-remove uuid=your-uuid-here param-name=other-config param-key=HideFromXenCenter

Comment: user160198 is correct, this should not be the accepted answer, as it deletes all other config parameters, not only the hidden key. Depending on your settings you could lose potential crucial keys.

Comment: I've copied the answer from the official Xen support page linked in. At that time (in 2011) this was the correct official solution. The answer was changed since then in the referenced link, so I've updated it here now.

Answer (score 3):

Current accepted answer is not safe to execute, as commented by @user160198, it will clear all params. This should have been an answer instead of comment.

> `xe vm-param-remove uuid=<vm-uuid> param-name=other-config param-key=HideFromXenCenter`